# Calculating the complexity of this function

Tags: c, time-complexity

This is the function:

```
void f(int n)
{
 for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
   for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
     for(int k=i*j; k>0; k/=2)
       printf("~");
}
```

In my opinion, the calculation of the time complexity would end up to be something like this:

```
log((n-1)(n-2))+log((n-1)(n-3))+...+log(n-1)+log((n-2)(n-3))+...+log(n-2)+...log(2)
```

So, I get a time complexity of `nlog(n!)` (because `loga+logb=log(a*b)` and because n-1,n-2,n-3,... each appears n-1 times in total.

However, the correct answer is `n^2*logn`, and I have no idea where my mistake is. Could anyone here help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log(n!)` can be approximated as `(n+1/2)log(n) - n + constant` (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138194/approximating-log-of-factorial)

So the complexity is `n*n*log(n)` as expected.

Simpler: compute the complexity loop by loop independently and multiply them.

First 2 outer loops: trivial: `n` each, which makes `n^2`

Inner loop: has a `log(n**2)` complexity which is the same as `log(n)`

So `n^2log(n)` is the correct answer.

Comment: Exactly. More precisely, first loop is n, second clearly n/2 average, and inner is some factor times log n²; and log n² is 2 log n. Then remove the constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

The Complexity is `O(N*N*LOG_2(N^2))`.

The first and the second loop both have `O(N)` and the last loop in `k` has logarithmic grow.

```
LOG_2(N^2) = 2*LOG_2(N) and
O(N*M)=O(N)*O(M).
O(constant)=1.
```

So for the grow of the last loop you can write also `O(LOG_2(N^2))=O(LOG(N))`.